# Error using "enum" within a class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, scope, declaration

I get the following error message about my enum, and I can't figure out why.
I have only 1 header file and only 1 source file where I implemented all the functions (and main). I declared the enum within class "Survivor", in "public". I didn't forget to include the header file in the source file. Please help me see what I've done wrong.

> "error: 'e_status' does not name a type"

This is my header file:

```
class Survivor
{
public:
    enum e_status {SINGLE, MARRIED, RELATIONSHIP};

    char* get_name();
    int get_age();
    e_status get_status();

    void set_name(char n[]);
    void set_age (int a);
    void set_status (e_status s);

    const void print();

private:

    char name [20];
    int age;
    e_status status;
};
```

This is the relevant part in my Source file:

```
e_status Survivor::get_status()
{
    return status;
}
```

Comment: Hint: you declared the enumeration inside the class definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a qualified name

```
Survivor::e_status Survivor::get_status()
{
    //...
}
```

The type `e_status` is a member of the class `Survivor`.

A return type of a member function is not searched in the class scope while for example a parameter type is used in the class scope.

Consider the following two function definitions.

```
#include <iostream>

class Survivor
{
public:
    enum e_status {SINGLE, MARRIED, RELATIONSHIP};

    e_status get_status();
    void set_status (e_status s);
    //...
private:
    e_status status;
};

Survivor::e_status Survivor::get_status()
{
    return status;
}

void Survivor::set_status (e_status s)
{
    status = s;
}

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also possible: `auto Survivor::get_status() -> e_status`. Useful if you want to avoid the qualified name at all costs, or just for illustration.

Comment: @anatolyg In this case the function must be declared the same way in the class definition. Take into account that the trailing return type specifier is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to reference outside the class; do this:

```
 Survivor::e_status Survivor::get_status()
```